# images div class in a grid, need to add overlay

Tags: css

I've used floating box to style images in a grid.

```
<style>
.floating-box {
display: inline-block;
width: 22%; 
}
</style>
```

Now I want to add a mouseover overlay, something simple like a 50% color overlay. But I can't work out how to add a second div style. When I look at the instructions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade), I don't understand how to combine the div styles (I don't need the text part of the example).

I've tried putting both styles, "floating-box" and "overlay", into the sheet and then using them together in the html; it didn't work.

```
<div class="floating-box overlay"><img src="#"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: get the same code and  change bottom:0 to bottom:50% .. and remove height:100%

Comment: `I've tried a few things but can't get it going.` What did you try? WOuld help to show what you've tried/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to add text to the overlay you can create the effect using a pseudoelement.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

div:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This did not work so I think what I'm trying to do is conflicting with my wordpress theme. Thank you so much for your help.